# Are all holomorphic functions $ f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ unbounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Is it true that $f$ must be unbounded or is this false? I think that it is false, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Constant functions?

Comment: But not all holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ are constant, right?

Comment: Right, but constants show they need not be unbounded, which was your question.  Did you mean to ask a different one?

Comment: Liouville's theorem state that all entire bounded function is constant, using this your statement is false.

Comment: Ahh ok, I misinterpreted your answer! So then it is correct to say that not all holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ are unbounded?

Comment: Liouville's theorem states that a *bounded* entire function is constant.  However, there are certainly unbounded entire functions.

Comment: Since a constant function is bounded and holomorphic, not all holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ are unbounded.  By Liouville, these are the only counterexamples.